# iOS 10.1.1 popup saying "Application May Slow Down Your iPhone"

Tags: ios, ios10

When I build and run my app through Xcode on my real device I get a popup saying:

> **AppName** May Slow Down Your iPhone
>
> The developer of this app needs to update it to improve its compatibility.

I dont see any memory issues, and I never had any problem with my app crashing.

So what is causing this scary message?

Answer (score 3):

This isn't a memory or a crash issue - it's Apple asking developers to update their [apps with only 32-bit support with 64-bit support](http://www.macrumors.com/2016/10/06/ios-10-1-32-bit-app-alert/).

You must build a 64-bit binary with your existing app.  To do so:

> Start by building the app for the 64-bit runtime, fixing any warnings that occur as well as searching your code for specific 64-bit issues. For example:
>
> - Make sure all function calls have a proper prototype.
> - Avoid truncating 64-bit values by accidentally assigning them to a 32-bit data type.
> - Ensure that calculations are performed correctly in the 64-bit version of your app.
> - Create data structures whose layouts are identical in the 32-bit and 64-bit versions of your app (such as when you write a data file to iCloud).

There's more information in [Apple's documentation on porting your app to 64-bit](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/General/Conceptual/CocoaTouch64BitGuide/Introduction/Introduction.html) as well.

Comment: I dont understand. I started to build my project when ios9 was released. I have only got this pop up once. Even though I have started my app hundered of times