# Warning when starting the codenameone App on iOS ("App slows down the device")

Tags: ios, warnings, codenameone

When I start my Debug-Build on an iOS-Device for the first time, a warning from apple is shown which says, that this App would slow down the device and should be re-engenired by the developer (don't know the exact text in english because it's shown in german for me).

In fact I cannot recognize any slow behavior - the app and all the rest works fine and performant. But it's a pity, that new users will be shown this warning on the first start of the App.

Do you have any idea, what the cause may be?

Comment: Can you put your device in english and get the full english version of the text?  Is it about 64-bit compatibility?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [iOS 10.1.1 popup saying "Application May Slow Down Your iPhone"](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40597208/ios-10-1-1-popup-saying-application-may-slow-down-your-iphone)

Comment: That's not a duplicate of that as it relates to Codename One and thus the answer is different

Answer (score 2):

This is answered [here](https://www.codenameone.com/blog/partners-demos-custom-gui-components-iphone-old-deprecation.html), the short answer is use the build hint `ios.debug.archs=arm64`. The longer answer is that debug builds only build for one platform and we default to 32bit for maximum compatibility.

By setting 64 bit the debug build won't work on older devices and despite Apples hyperbole you won't perceive any performance difference. Notice that release/appstore builds include both versions but take longer to build and are almost double the size.

Comment: Thx for your answer - I will try this build hint.